# Significant Partial Autocorrelations at High Lags

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, lags

[image: Raw Time Series]I've been doing some exploratory data analysis on a time series dataset and had some questions about interpreting a PACF plot that I generated. I initially displayed the plot with a maximum lag of 400, and saw some significant autocorrelations, after 1 day, 6 days, 7 days, 364 days, and 365 days, after which the PACs seemed to decay. I thought that this was indicative of some significant daily, weekly, and yearly lag.

However, I decided to generate the PACF graph again with maximum lag of 1200 and was surprised to see many high autocorrelations even at higher lags (800+). I'm confused on how to interpret these autocorrelations. Do they suggest significant multiyear autocorrelation, or is it incorrect to assume that autocorrelations at high lags can be interpreted like this? Any pointers or links to useful resources would be appreciated. Thanks[image]

Comment: What is the underlying time series?

Comment: Hi, the time series is the daily number of new users who register for an app. The end goal is to build a model that can forecast how many users will sign up on a given day. After reviewing the data, I've realized that the underlying time series is nonstationary. Would I need to transform to stationary in order to make sense of ACF and PACF? Thanks!

Comment: I think so. You could include a graph of raw data, too.

Comment: Thanks, I've included a graph of the raw time series in the original post. There does seem to be some upward trend and seasonality, so perhaps this explains the strange PACF behavior.

Comment: You need a *multiplicative* model, not an additive one. A simple approach is to analyze the logarithms of the counts.

Comment: @whuber, I see. So if I apply the log transformation to my user counts, would I be able to test for stationarity using tests like ADF and KPSS, and build models accordingly if stationarity is met?

Comment: As for the issue with high partial correlation at large lags, this seems to be a recurring issue with the default method that the Python stats models library uses to calculated PACF. When I specified the method as 'ywmle', autocorrelation decayed/converged as expected with larger lags.

Comment: You don't need to test for stationarity: the trend and seasonality are large and obvious.  First adjust for trend and seasonality and only then consider whether the residuals are stationary.